# Why does my site flash white every time it changes page?

Tags: server-load, performance, cache

Any ideas?  I've never had this problem before.

[Here is the site.](http://sugarstreetreview.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your site is doing a lot of processing when displaying a page.

have you tried adding a caching mechanism?

you can give plugin a try:  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/

Comment: Is there a reason why it would be doing a lot of processing? It's a fairly basic site built on the Thematic theme. I'll try the plugin but I experienced exactly the same issue when running the site locally using MAMP...

Comment: from my experience the first things to look at are plugins.  try to disable all plugins and enable them one-by-one to see if you can spot one that slows down your page load.

Comment: Thank you! You were spot on. Disabled a plugin and it pretty much stopped the white flashes, then installed Hyper Cache and it stopped them altogether and made the site super fast!

Comment: Hmm spoke too soon. I'm now occasionally getting a split second white flash. I'll try disabling some other plugins

Comment: YSLow indicate there are several things you can do to speed up your site: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/

Answer (score 0):

That would be the page being rendered serverside and what not. Every site does it, but since your site is on a (relatively) dark background, it's more pronounced...it sucks on black sites. You can probably minimize that with some sort of caching...but oyu're just gonna have to play around with it.

Comment: But I built this site with a black background and it doesn't do it - http://bit.ly/y1xPIQ - both are on dreamhost server

Comment: Heh, well this is odd. I just clicked around on it a bunch, and it will only occasionally flash...maybe it's something to do with how long it takes for a resource to expire or something.